# Logging Gulp console output to a file

Tags: logging, console, gulp

I am using Gulp as a part of a simple build system for processing text and images, and have defined a series of generic tasks for copying, processing, and deleting these files. Both Gulp and the plugins used give a lot of output in the console, but how can this output be preserved in a file?

Ideally, the exact contents of the console would be logged to `console.log` in the same format as it appeared in the console (without color, as is common in the console):

```
[13:35:21] Images: 208 items
[13:35:23] gulp-imagemin: Minified 208 images (saved 0 B - 0%)
[13:35:23] Finished 'build:images' after 19 s
[13:35:23] Starting 'clean:responsive'...
[13:35:23] Deleting /responsive/**/*
[13:35:23] Finished 'clean:responsive' after 171 ms
[13:35:23] Starting 'default'...
[13:35:23] Finished 'default' after 57 μs
```

Many of the Gulp plugins focused on logging seem to mainly do this in the console, which is already achieved, and only [gulp-messenger](https://github.com/mikeerickson/gulp-messenger) saved it to text (as json). Can this be achieved with for example [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util)?

Comment: That's not really a job for a gulp plugin. You should simply redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a file when you invoke gulp. On any Unix system this should do the trick: `gulp task-name > output.log 2>&1`.

Comment: I hadn't really thought of that, but your example works (even on Windows).  Only, it suppresses the console output in favor of logging it. Can both occur? I guess it has something to do with `2>&1`, but not quite sure how to interpret that.

Comment: `2>&1` redirects STDERR (2) to STDOUT (1) effectively "merging" the two. Logging to the console and a file on Linux works like this: `gulp task-name 2>&1 | tee output.log`. No clue about Windows.

Comment: `gulp task-name 2>&1 | tee output.log` works on Windows too, at least in Cmder. Though without the colors from the plugins, but those are not needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Sven Schoenung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892036/sven-schoenung) suggests in comments, this is best done outside of Gulp itself. In essence, when running the task in terminal two options work as expected:

To run "silently", that is, without console output:

`gulp task-name > output.log 2>&1`

To run "normally", that is, with console output:

`gulp task-name 2>&1 | tee output.log`

Both will save the output of the console to `output.log` in the root of the Gulp working directory.